# Read only specific fields from large JSON and import into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder with more or less 10 json files that size between 500 and 1000 Mb.
Each file contains about 1.000.000 of lines like the loffowling:

```
{ 
    "dateTime": '2019-01-10 01:01:000.0000'
    "cat": 2
    "description": 'This description'
    "mail": 'mail@mail.com'
    "decision":[{"first":"01", "second":"02", "third":"03"},{"first":"04", "second":"05", "third":"06"}] 
    "Field001": 'data001'
    "Field002": 'data002'
    "Field003": 'data003'
    ...
    "Field999": 'data999'
}
```

My target is to analyze it with pandas so I would like to save the data coming from all the files into a Dataframe.
If I loop all the files Python crash because I don't have free resources to manage the data.

**As for my purpose I only need a Dataframe with two columns `cat` and `dateTime` from all the files, which I suppose is lighter that a whole Dataframe with all the columns I have tryed to read only these two columns with the following snippet:**

*Note: at the moment I am working with only one file, when I get a fast reader code I will loop to all other files (A.json, B.json, ...)*

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os.path
from glob import glob

cols = ['cat', 'dateTime']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

file_name='this_is_my_path/File_A.json'
with open(file_name, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=json.loads(line)
        lst_dict=({'cat':data['cat'], 'dateTime':data['dateTime']})
        df = df.append(lst_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

**The code works, but it is very very slow so it takes more than one hour for one, file while reading all the file and storing into a Dataframe usually takes me 8-10 minutes.**

Is there a way to read only two specific columns and append to a Dataframe in a faster way?

I have tryed to read all the JSON file and store into a Dataframe, then drop all the columns but 'cat' and 'dateTime' but it seems to be too heavy for my MacBook.

Comment: I think this is the fastest way, but i don't really understand the party where you say it takes one hour with this code.
But with other code it takes like 8-10 mins? I think 8-10 mins sfor files that big is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found out that appending a dict to a DataFrame is very very slow. Extract the values as a list instead. In my case it took 14 s instead of 2 h.

```
cols = ['cat', 'dateTime']
data = []
file_name = 'this_is_my_path/File_A.json'

with open(file_name, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        doc = json.loads(line)
        lst = [doc['cat'], doc['dateTime']]
        data.append(lst)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
```

Comment: I guess that when working too much with json we start thinking data only as documents ^^

Answer (score -13):

Will this help?

Step 1.
Read your json file from pandas 
"pandas.read_json() "
Step 2.
Then filter out your 2 columns from the dataframe.

Let me know if you still face any issue.
Thanks

Comment: This is not a general solution. I face similar problems and the first command `pandas.read_json()` already exceeds memory. The option `chunksize` will not help either, since you cannot perform aggregate operations on `'JsonReader'` objects.

Comment: @fcpenha  Same, the point of this question is to NOT import all the columns due to resource restrictions.